# Proof from Axioms for a Ring

Tags: proof-verification

I'm trying to prove this following theorem:

> If $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, use the cancellation law for $\mathbb{Z}$ to demonstrate that $xy = 0 \implies$ $x = 0$ or $y = 0$

The proof I came up with doesn't quite seem definitive enough. I know how to prove this without using the cancellation law, but this requirement seems to make things much more difficult.

So, clearly $0 = 0 \cdot x = 0 \cdot y$ $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, we can clearly say that this holds for $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

So, first we can write that $xy = 0 \cdot x$ for $x \neq 0$. So, by the cancellation law, $y = 0$. Similarily, we can write that $xy =0 \cdot y$ for $y \neq 0$, so $x = 0$ by the cancellation law.

It seems to me that we can write $xy = 0 \cdot a$ for any integer, so this doesn't quite "prove" anything, though in such a case we wouldn't be able to use the cancellation law, so that wouldn't at all be a pertinent fact.

How does this sound?

Comment: Which is the "cancellation law" (for $\Bbb Z$) ?

Comment: I believe it is that, for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \cdot y = y \cdot z \wedge z \neq 0 \implies x = y$. At least, this is the theorem I should be using, though it's possible that this is a more colloquial name for it.

Comment: Then assume the contrary, that both $x,y$ are not zero and get the contradiction from $x0=xy=0y$.

Comment: >"So, first we can write that $xy=0⋅x$ for $x≠0$. So, by the cancellation law, $y=0$. **Similarily, we can write that $xy=0⋅y$ for $y≠0$, so $x=0$ by the cancellation law**" 

But wait, if $x\ne 0$ then $x=0$, no need the second part.

Comment: "It seems to me that we can write xy=0⋅a for any integer, so this doesn't quite "prove" anything"  What do you mean.  You just *proved* either $y=0$ or $x=0$.  So why does $xy = 0*a$ cancel that?  If you have to prove George was an American and you proved that George was born in Maine and said "Yeah, but this would be true of *everybody* born in Maine so it doesn't prove anything" um.... why not?

Comment: If $xy = 0*a$ then $xy*y^{-1} = 0*(ay^{-1}) $ so $x = 0$.  No, difference.  That *still* proves  .... everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me that we can write $xy=0⋅a$ for any integer, so this doesn't quite "prove" anything,

And if $y\ne 0$ you can write $x = x*y*y^{-1} = 0*a*y^{-1} = 0*(a*y^{-1}) = 0$ for any integer.  So that proves everything.

Answer (score 0):

The cancellation law says that if $c\ne 0$ and $ac = bc$ then $a=b$.

If $xy=0$ and $x\ne 0$, then since $xy = x0$, $y=0$.